# How can I fit more things on my Mac Menu Bar?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I have a MacBook Pro 16 inch, and because of the camera notch, I have very limited space on my Menu Bar (the top right part of the screen). Because of this, I can only see a handful of applications that use the menu bar. Just to name a few I have Dropbox, Caffeine, a bunch of iStat Menu icons, Scroll reverser, Alfred.

This has become really frustrating for me, for when say I want to turn on/off Caffeine but it is not present on my Menu Bar because it's hidden and I have to close other applications on my menu bar to see it.

How can I increase the space on my Menu Bar? On Windows I have a system tray where I can access my background running applications, does Mac have anything similar?

Comment: Do you mean something like Bartender Bar? https://www.macbartender.com

Comment: Get rid of iStat menus..? ;-) Do you really need to check CPU, memory, etc all the time? Just use Activity Monitor when there's a problem.

Comment: @benwiggy best of both worlds: use the istatmenus battery indicator (better than the built-in one imo) so as not to take up additional room, and keep the other handy stats a click away

Comment: Same issue, but slightly different cause in the linked dupe, but answers are the same - you need some sort of menu bar management/customization tool.

Answer (score 5):

For this I strongly recommend [Bartender](https://www.macbartender.com), which lets you hide most menu-bar items behind a little disclosure toggle, and selectively/temporarily show them based on various rules (e.g. show wifi only when disconnected, show dropbox only when syncing, show Carbon Copy Cloner only when there's an error).

[image: partial screenshot of bartender in action]

Comment: In addition, and relevant to the question, Bartender has 3 spacing options - default (large), like it used to be, and no spacing.

Answer (score 5):

There is a free alternative to Bartender I found, though not as feature-laden, called [Hidden Bar](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/hidden-bar/id1452453066) which lets you hide menubar icons behind a toggle.

Update: Though I have *not* tried it, I did find another free app from the app store called [iBar-Menubar icon control tool](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ibar-menubar-icon-control-tool/id6443843900) which does look more robust.